# Repetition while importing multiple CSV into one data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to import multiple csv files by using

```
df <- ldply(list.files(), read.csv, header= TRUE )
```

I was able to import all the files into one data frame but the problem is the months seem to keep repeating as shown in df1

```
 >df1
  Months     A    B     C
1 Jan        2    NA    NA
2 Feb        3    NA    NA
3 Mar        4    NA    NA
4 Jan       NA     5    NA
5 Feb       NA     6    NA
6 Mar       NA     1    NA
7 Jan       NA    NA     4
8 Feb       NA    NA     1
9 Mar       NA    NA     3


> df1
structure(list(Months = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), A = c(2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), B = c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 6, 1, NA, NA, NA), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4, 1, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I would like to achieve is

```
  >df2
  Months       A     B    C
  1 Jan        2     5    4
  2 Feb        3     6    1
  3 Mar        4     1    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep only unique values for character columns and drop `NA` values from numeric columns. We can write a function for this.

```
keep_vals <- function(x) {
  if(is.character(x)) unique(x) else na.omit(x)
}
```

Now apply this function for each column.

Using `lapply` in base R :

```
result <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df1, keep_vals))
result

#  Months A B C
#1    Jan 2 5 4
#2    Feb 3 6 1
#3    Mar 4 1 3
```

Or a bit shorter with `purrr::map_dfc`.

```
result <- purrr::map_dfc(df1, keep_vals)
```